# Export Sharepoint list to CSV, then create a working XML file

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I am trying to export a SharePoint (365 online) list using PowerShell. 
Export result should go to CSV. From there I want to grab the infromation and merge it into a XML for directory listing.

Directly Listing output should be.

```xml
<YeastarIPPhoneDirectory>     

<DirectoryEntry>    
  <Name>Reception</Name>    
  <Telephone>200</Telephone>    
</DirectoryEntry>


<DirectoryEntry>    
  <Name>User1</Name>    
  <Telephone>201</Telephone>    
</DirectoryEntry> 

<DirectoryEntry>    
  <Name>User2</Name>  
  <Telephone>202</Telephone>    
</DirectoryEntry>
```

My SharePoint list contains all the relevant info Name and ext number.
The verbals are "user" and the extension number.

This then needs to be automated to run daily.

The code I have so far:

```bsh
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$LiveCred = Get-Credential

$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "https://*.sharepoint.com/IT/Lists/VOIP%20Extentions/"

$list = $web.Lists["Voip%20Extentions"]

$ListItemCollection = @()
$list.Items | Where-Object { $_["Status"] -eq "In Progress" } | foreach {
    $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Wxt" -Value $_["Ext"]
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $_["Name"]

    $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
}
$ListItemCollection | Export-Csv "c:\Phonelist.txt" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Please tell us what your code succeeds in or fails to do at the moment. Is [ConvertTo-Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-xml) what you're looking for?

Comment: The current code exports to plain txt or csv, either works, But i need to create an xml file from that csv to import into :

Comment: Why do you want to export the data to a CSV and then create the XML from that instead of creating the XML directly? Also, since the CSV export code is apparently working, please show the *non-working* XML conversion code, so that we may provide assistance with that.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the data to XML, use the `ConvertTo-Xml` cmdlet.

```
# convert to XML and save to file
$ListItemCollection | ConvertTo-Xml -As String -NoTypeInformation | Out-File -FilePath 'c:\Phonelist.xml' -Encoding utf8
```

Also, I would change the way you collect the data in the `$ListItemCollection` variable to avoid using array concatenation with `$ListItemCollection += $ExportItem` like this:

```
$ListItemCollection = $list.Items |  Where-Object { $_["Status"] -eq "In Progress"} | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        "Wxt"  = $_["Ext"]
        "Name" = $_["Name"]
    }
 }
```

Or customize the XML by using the XmlTextWriter class:

```
# Set The Formatting
$xmlsettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$xmlsettings.Indent      = $true
$xmlsettings.IndentChars = "    "

# Set the File Name Create The Document
$XmlWriter = [System.XML.XmlWriter]::Create("D:\test.xml", $xmlsettings)

# Write the XML Decleration and set the XSL
$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()

# Start the Root Element
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("YeastarIPPhoneDirectory")
# write the data
$ListItemCollection | ForEach-Object {
    $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("DirectoryEntry")
        $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Name", $_.Name)
        $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Telephone", $_.Wxt)
    $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()                   # End <DirectoryEntry>
}
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()                       # End <YeastarIPPhoneDirectory> 

# End, Finalize and close the XML Document
$xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
$xmlWriter.Flush()
$xmlWriter.Close()
```

This creates an xml:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <YeastarIPPhoneDirectory>
>     <DirectoryEntry>
>         <Name>Reception</Name>
>         <Telephone>200</Telephone>
>     </DirectoryEntry>
>     <DirectoryEntry>
>         <Name>User1</Name>
>         <Telephone>201</Telephone>
>     </DirectoryEntry>
>     <DirectoryEntry>
>         <Name>User2</Name>
>         <Telephone>202</Telephone>
>     </DirectoryEntry>
> </YeastarIPPhoneDirectory>
> ```

Hope that helps